# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined index: elements_id Filename: views/showdetail.php Line Number: 17

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: elements_id

Filename: views/showdetail.php

### Line Number: 17

Help me please!
Error on server openshift but Run on localhost no error.
How to fix?

Comment: This means an array index 'elements_id' doesn't exist and it is trying to be accessed.  It is not an error necessarily, it is a notice.  A notice is not an error.  Do you have notices reporting on your localhost?

Comment: No notices localhost.

Answer (score 2):

Do this with each variable

```
$elements_id=isset($row['elements_id'])?$row['elements_id']):'';
```

You are trying to use the vale of the index of the array without checking first if is set

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php 
        print_r($dataelements);
         foreach ($dataelements as $row) { 
                $elements_id =$row['elements_id'];
                $elements_number = $row['elements_number'];
                $elements_name = $row['elements_name'];
                $elements_principle = $row['elements_principle'];
                $elements_standard = $row['elements_standard'];
                $elements_indicator = $row['elements_indicator'];
                
         }
        ?>
```